# Franchise business failed due to franchisor fraud, NDA signed, how to list on resume / linked In

Tags: resume, linkedin, job-description, non-disclosure-agreement

I recently took a chance to started a franchise business on the side of my normal job. During the course of the franchise myself and other locations became aware of fraud being committed by the franchisor and sued. As a part of our settlement we signed NDA's to not reveal the specifics of our settlement, or the fact our business closed due to his fraud.

Having run this business for several years, I think it is valuable experience that I should have on my resume. I also listed on my linkedin account that I was the owner of this business since opening. I feel just taking that completely off my page now will appear odd.

How is the best way to handle this? Or what should be put on the resume description?

Comment: Why would you take it off? The NDA is about thye reason you closed not that you have to pretend you never had the business

Comment: I think this depends on *exactly* what you're allowed to say under the terms of your NDA. If what you're not allowed to say is "fraud", say "illegal activities". In any case, you probably want to talk to your solicitor to clear whatever you do say.

Comment: @PhilipKendall why does he have to say anything ? I wouldn't mention illegal activities or fraud in a resume

Comment: Wasn't trying to say I was pretending to not have the business, but it wouldn't look strange or bad that I closed a business I opened 2 years prior on a resume?

Answer (score 6):

Include the usual resume stuff: Dates, company name, location, your role(s) and accomplishments.

The resume is not the place to explain why you no longer work there. When the subject comes up in the phone call or interview, you can simply say that the franchise arrangement ended. If they ask for details, you simply explain that the details are protected by a non-disclosure agreement.

It's actually up to you to read and understand what your NDA covers and to decide what you can or cannot share. You should get professional legal advice. If the job interview turns to the subject of your ability to successfully operate a business, you'll need to know the specifics of what you can't freely share.